# How can I execute commands on a remote computer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, powershell, remote-desktop

I have a machine that I am able to connect using the `Remote Desktop Connection` application and it is on a different domain. This machine has a SQL Server that can ONLY be accessed when I attempt to access it after logging into this machine.

Is it possible (either via C# or Powershell or some other mechanism) to initiate something like an `ssh` connection to this machine, execute the `sqlcmd` command and copy back the data?

Comment: Do you have to do this at some sort of regular interval? I was thinking maybe do it the other way around: Have a Task run on the other box execute the sql command and send you the data... depending on how large the data is you could dome something on your end?

Comment: Try this article http://www.maxtblog.com/2011/09/no-hassle-sql-server-remoting-with-powershell-v2/

Comment: @Icarus: Thank you. The data can get pretty big so what I generally do is to pipe my `sqlcmd` into gzip, compress the data and transfer it to my local machine. In addition, I am doing this on demand so the query is not at a regular interval but more of a one-time query.

Comment: What is the reason that it can only be accessed from RDP? Knowing that will help to formulate a solution better. If not, you should be able to connect using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx

Comment: Are you an *administrator* on the remote machine, or have you just been granted remote desktop permissions? Also, do you know whether there are any network restrictions between you and the remote machine (i.e. a firewall that only has the RDP port open...)?

Comment: @JustinKing: I will give it a shot and get back if it works.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I have been granted permissions. I was playing around with PowerShell and then finally encountered an error saying that `Access is Denied`. I have emailed my admin to see if something can be done about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

It allows you to run a command prompt on a remote machine

Comment: Fails with the same `Access is denied` message. Nevertheless must be something wrong on my side. +1 for the tool. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite open - PowerShell V2 does allow you to connect remotely (some config is required and Ravi's written a great guide here -http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?cat=240)

This will give you an overview on the command to configure PS Remoting.

```
help Enable-PSRemoting
```

Depending on your setup you may just need to run this.

**However** your question sound like something is not quite right (or right if it's by design but why?) with your SQL set up.

> This machine has a SQL Server that can ONLY be accessed when I attempt
>   to access it after logging into this machine.

Is there a reason you can't initiate a SQL connection directly to the server?

Comment: +1 Thank you. Yes. The domains do not trust each other I am guessing. I am not entirely sure of Windows permission model but the admins have made it such that I domain names of the SQL servers are only accessible after logging into this remote machine.

Comment: so you log on to this remote server (VPN maybe?) and then you can access the SQL server, from the remote machine?

Comment: Yes I log on but its not VPN. Vanilla Remote Desktop Connection in Windows.